# str.extract vs str.count regex usage in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand why `str.extract"([\d+%])"` returns `NaN` while `str.count"([\d+%])"` returns the correct answer when parsing text within a column of a dataframe.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject':['3 hrs only! 35% off', 'Secret Savings!', 'Sale: 40% off']})
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+%)")
df['Discount'] = df['Subject'].str.count(pattern)
```

...yields a Discount column with "1's" in row 1 and 3 as you would expect. However,

```
df['Discount'] = df['Subject'].str.extract(pattern)
```

...returns NaNs instead. I cannot understand why count can parse the percentages but extract does not. This is driving me a little crazy as it seems like it should be straightforward.

Comment: I think you've got your quotes and parenthesis in the wrong order... `"(...)"` vs `("...")`

Comment: Your little example works fine for me. However, there is a bug with `extract` for pandas 0.13.1 (it's fixed in master). See here: [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6498). If you set the index to something besides the initial default of [0,1,2,...,N], then `extract` return NaNs. So if I change the index to ['a','b','c'] in you example, I also get all NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

The [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6498) was fixed in the subsequent Pandas version.

Now, with Pandas  0.24.2, you may use

```
>>> df.index=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> df
               Subject Discount
a  3 hrs only! 35% off      35%
b      Secret Savings!      NaN
c        Sale: 40% off      40%
>>> df['Subject'].str.extract(pattern)
     0
a  35%
b  NaN
c  40%
```